# Split CSV files using a specific line

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I would like to split the following csv into two csvs

```
StartOrder,1,SupplierName,
Line,2,12345,2,5,5.50,
Line,3,12345,3,6,5.20,
Line,4,12345,3,7,1.99,
EndOrder,5,booked as soon as possible to deliver.
StartOrder,6,SupplierName
Line,7,100015,2,5,5.50,
Line,8,100015,3,6,5.20,
Line,9,100015,3,7,1.99,
EndOrder,10,booked as soon as possible to deliver.
```

in order to be:

1st file

```
StartOrder,1,SupplierName,
Line,2,12345,2,5,5.50,
Line,3,12345,3,6,5.20,
Line,4,12345,3,7,1.99,
EndOrder,5,booked as soon as possible to deliver.
```

2nd file

```
StartOrder,6,SupplierName
Line,7,100015,2,5,5.50,
Line,8,100015,3,6,5.20,
Line,9,100015,3,7,1.99,
EndOrder,10,booked as soon as possible to deliver.
```

I have tried using GroupBy but is not working as I am expecting.

Any help?

Comment: Can you show us your code?
Also, is each order only 3 lines? And is it always 3 lines?

Comment: Get-ChildItem $in -Recurse |
  ForEach-Object {
  Get-Content $_.FullName | Group-Object { $_-replace ',.*' -replace '"' } |
  ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Out-File ($out+$_.Name)
  }
  }

Comment: no is not always 3 lines

Comment: How have you used group-by? Sounds like you just want to parse the line prefixes in a loop and cut to a new output file redirection when you see StartOrder

Comment: correct, this is what i need to do

Comment: If you show us your group by example if would be you showing an attempt for a solution as supposed to the code writing request this appears as now. FWIW I would not use `group-object` and would instead read in the file at once and split on "StartOrder" or read in lines one at a time and react to a StartOrder line to change the output which would be simpler.

Comment: Get-ChildItem $in -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_.FullName | Group-Object { $_-replace ',.*' -replace '"' } | ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Out-File ($out+$_.Name) } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something i would do with Regular Expressions.

```
    $orders = (get-content -path C:\temp\orders.txt)    
    $orders = [string]::Join("`n",$orders)    # this is to make sure you keep your lines
    $output = [regex]::Matches($orders,'(?s)(StartOrder,(\d{0,}).*?deliver.)') # added regex option S

foreach($c in $output){                
    $order = $c.groups[2].value #order name that will serve as filename
    ""
    $c.groups[0].value # content of order
    $c.groups[0].value  | out-file C:\temp\$order.txt -Force
}
```

This wil create a 1.txt and a 6.txt with its needed content.

**EDIT** : The only issue is that it doesn't keep the enters. -> **FIXED THAT**

The Regex is fairly simple, more detail on the regex : https://regex101.com/r/J0Xsu7/1

This will give you file 1.txt with

```
StartOrder,1,SupplierName,
Line,2,12345,2,5,5.50,
Line,3,12345,3,6,5.20,
Line,4,12345,3,7,1.99,
EndOrder,5,booked as soon as possible to deliver.
```

This will give you file 6.txt with

```
StartOrder,6,SupplierName
Line,7,100015,2,5,5.50,
Line,8,100015,3,6,5.20,
Line,9,100015,3,7,1.99,
EndOrder,10,booked as soon as possible to deliver.
```